# Webview is not shown where i placed it in xml file, when testing. Why..?

Tags: android, xml, webview

I have used a webview to show text in "justify" alignment. My Problem is that when i test the app, the webview is shown at the bottom of the activity. This is the content of the xml file. Where as, i have placed it in between company website and support link. basically i need to show it after the "company profile"... How can i do it....?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/infoll"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="5dp"
android:paddingRight="5dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="InfoContent"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Company Website : "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/company_website"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="example link"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#0000FF" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Company Profile : "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Support link for app : "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/support_link"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="example link"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#0000FF" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**This is how i loaded data into webview programmatically.**
    infoActivity.java

```
    `setContentView(R.layout.layout_info);
            WebView view = new WebView(this);
    view.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);

    ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.infoll)).addView(view);

    view.loadData(getString(R.string.info), "text/html", "utf-8");`
```

**This is the string i am loading into the webview**
    strings.xml

```
    `<string name="info">
<![CDATA[
<html>
<head></head>
<body style="text-align:justify;color:gray;background-color:white;">
    Dummy content Dummy content Dummy content Dummy content Dummy content Dummy content Dummy content Dummy content Dummy content Dummy content Dummy content Dummy content Dummy content Dummy content Dummy content Dummy content  Dummy content.
</body>
</html>
]]></string>`
```

could it be because the loading of data into webview programmatically...?
Thanks in advance

[This is what i am getting right now(SCREENSHOT 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgxfT.png)

[This is what i am getting when i added layout_height=100dp for the webview(SCREENSHOT 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2k67q.png)
Basically i want my webview in that blank space

Comment: Have you loaded data in web view?

Comment: You could try setting a height, rather than setting it to wrap content - since the layout doesn't know what height to assign statically.

Comment: I think you should fix a height.

You can try with  android:weightSum so you can fix how and where your view will be shown

Comment: @Nitesh I have loaded some data into it programmatically.... The problem i am facing is that, in the xml i have placed the webview after the "company profile"(textview4) and "support link for app"(textview6). The webview shows the data as i want when i test it, but it is placed below the textview6 during runtime

Comment: You add a new Webview rather than use the webview in xml.

Comment: I needed to show some text in "justify" alignment. Since android doesn't support justify, i did some websurfing and found that, it can be done using webview and html in the string. That is what i have done. I am not using the webview to show some data from the web.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Company Profile : "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

android:layout_height="wrap_content"
to LinearLayout which is webview's parent is the reason why you not able to see the webview.

Give some weight to that linearlayout like below and try again.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Company Profile : "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I tried this but the result is same, a blank space where the webview is supposed to be and the webview is at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

`setContentView(R.layout.layout_info);

error:
            WebView view = new WebView(this);
    view.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);

```
((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.infoll)).addView(view);
```

right :
WebView view = findViewById(R.id.webview);

```
view.loadData(getString(R.string.info), "text/html", "utf-8");`
```

Comment: When i put a value for layout_height(300dp), during runtime a blank space is shown at that place for 300dp. and the webview is still at the bottom.

Comment: Plz update you latest xml code and where you loadUrl()

Comment: I have updated my question, there you can see the java code i used to load data into the webview and the string that i am loading into it. The xml is same